# Can you control the native interface after pressing the dialer button on Android?

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app and I'm stuck. Here's the scenario that I have:

1. The user picks a contact to call
2. The user presses the dialer button to call that contact
3. Android's native dial screen pops up i.e. Dialing Contact screen

Here's what I want to do:
After pressing the dialer button, is there any way for my app to control what pops up after pressing the dialer button?

Resources and tutorials are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the dialer app (just the part where you dial the number) that can be done by adding the dial intent to activity's intent filter in the manifest. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

If you're talking about accessing in call screen (where the number has already been dialed and/or you can get a dial tone) then you're a bit out of luck. The in-call screen is currently a protected part of the low level OS and we can't mess with it while staying within the confines of the API.